# Access <>-keys on US-keyboard when using QWERTZ-layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

My current notebook has a US-layout (i.e. QWERTY, with the lowest row being SHIFT, Z, X...), but for my daily use I would like to use the german layout (i.e. a QWERTZ-layout) in Windows 10. Unfortunately, in this layout I don't know how to access the <>-key (as it does not exist physically on this keyboard where it should be on a traditional QWERTZ-layout).
Are there other solutions I could use to access this key, as I use it quite frequently, without having to switch forth and back between the US-layout in Windows, and the german one?

Comment: In German layout, do you a key between the Shift and the Y? This key is supposed to have these two characters. ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout))

Comment: No, this key is missing, that's my problem. I have this keyboard in hardware: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards#/media/File:KB_United_States-NoAltGr.svg, but set it in Windows to QWERTZ, i.e. the german layout. Now, the lower left key is missing in hardware.

Comment: Does the On-Screen Keyboard (`%windir%\system32\osk.exe`) show these characters?

Comment: @harrymc: Yes, it is showing those characters. The key is just missing in hardware

Comment: You can easily repurpose other keys or key-combinations to give these characters. Which would be your preferences?